# Export Activities associated with CiviCase

Tags: activities, civicase, drupal-views, export

We're currently discussing whether it's possible to use the activities recorded in a Case (including the scheduled activities in a timeline), export them into Excel and convert it into a Gantt chart, but I can't see a way to export all activities associated with a Case. When I look at the options in the Civi Reports, it will only export the most recent activity. Would Drupal Views be any use?

Answer (score 3):

One thing that has annoyed me for years is the lack of a working Gantt Module or CiviCRM Extension. Due to the many ways people use Drupal and CiviCRM, I created an “Instruction Guide” (With Code Samples) rather than a module or extension.

You can get it here:https://github.com/jdgamsterdam/d9civicrmgantt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would be able to do that with Drupal Views. There is also an extension that provides the Case Activities with the API: https://civicrm.org/extensions/caseactivity-api

Comment: That's just what I want! I notice that it's compatible with 4.4 and we're using 4.6 - is it likely to work with 4.6 or do I need to use Views in the meantime?

Comment: Try with 4.6, I have not tested it yet with 4.6 but there is a good chance it will work.